# Storing generic type parameter for future usage

Tags: delphi

I have a few TFrames which descend from TRootFrame. Im showing those frames via a method with a Generic parameter like:

```
    class
      ..

    procedure Push<T:TFrameRoot>;

    end.
    
    Implementation
        
    procedure TFormMain.Push<T>(const closeMenu: Boolean);
    begin
    
      ShowFrame<T>();
    
      if closeMenu then
        DoCloseMenu();

    end;
```

This all works great and now I want to push the frames shown on a stack so that I can pop it later like:

```
procedure TFormMain.Push<T>(const closeMenu: Boolean);
begin

  fFrameStack.Push(T);

  ShowFrame<T>();

    if closeMenu then
        DoCloseMenu();
end;  

procedure TFormMain.Pop<T>();
var 
  frameType:T;
begin

  frameType := fFrameStack.Pop();

  ShowFrame<frameType as T>();

end;
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks, Edward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `ShowFrame<T:TFrameRoot>` to `ShowFrame(frameClass: TFrameRootClass)` and declare `TFrameRootClass = class of TFrameRoot`.
Because your `T` is constrained to `TFrameRoot` you can simply assign `T` to a variable of `TFrameRootClass` variable/parameter. Also `fFrameStack` is a `Stack<TFrameRootClass>`

```
procedure TFormMain.ShowFrame(frameRootClass: TFrameRootClass);
begin
end;

procedure TFormMain.Push<T>(const closeMenu: Boolean);
begin
  fFrameStack.Push(T);

  ShowFrame(T);
end;

procedure TFormMain.Pop<T>();
var
  frameType: TFrameRootClass;
begin
  frameType := fFrameStack.Pop();

  ShowFrame(frameType);
end;
```

Personal advice: if you constrain your generic type parameter to some class anyway it often makes no sense to have a generic at all but rather use a class reference (that `class of ...` thing).

You can easily get away with making your `Push` and `Pop` method simply take a parameter of `TFrameRootClass`.